# Code igniter always escaping my SELECT ... CASE query

Tags: codeigniter

I am using Codeigniter to fire a query on my db. The code looks like:

```
$this->db->select("category.Name,
booking.Comment,
CASE WHEN amount > 0 THEN amount END AS PosAmount,
CASE WHEN amount < 0 THEN amount END AS NegAmount");
```

But I always get an

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax ... right syntax to use near
'WHEN amount > 0 THEN amount END AS PosAmount, `CASE` WHEN amount < 0 
THEN amount' at line 1
```

Codeigniter is escaping the CASE but I do not know how to prevent this.

Any ideas?

Comment: $query=$this->db->query("category.Name,
booking.Comment,
CASE WHEN amount > 0 THEN amount END AS PosAmount,
CASE WHEN amount < 0 THEN amount END AS NegAmount"); $query->result();

Comment: That is just adding the String to the actual query?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#selecting-data) :

> `$this->db->select()` accepts an optional second parameter. If you set it to `FALSE`, CodeIgniter will not try to protect your field or table names. This is useful if you need a compound select statement where automatic escaping of fields may break them.

In your case :

```
$this->db->select("category.Name,
booking.Comment,
CASE WHEN amount > 0 THEN amount END AS PosAmount,
CASE WHEN amount < 0 THEN amount END AS NegAmount", FALSE);
```

This second parameter can also be used in where and join clauses.